# How to restart a Service Fabric Application

Tags: service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a gMSA service account running a stateless Service Fabric application.  The account has recently been added as a member to a new security group.  We don't see that the application is working and I think its because the user claims were loaded on application start up.  I've seen that to get this to work on Windows Services that we need to restart the service (mmc->Services, right click restart).  I would like to do something similar in Service Fabric.

I see the option of restarting the node, but that is a more heavy handed approach than I want to use.  This is in production and I want to scope the solution to the problem.  The other applications on the node do not have an issue so I would prefer to not bring them down.

[Service Fabric Deactivate (pause) vs Deactivate (restart)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308701/service-fabric-deactivate-pause-vs-deactivate-restart)

Thanks in advance, 
Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/restart-servicefabricdeployedcodepackage?view=azureservicefabricps) command.

> The ***Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage*** cmdlet ends the code package process, which restarts all of the user service replicas hosted in that process. This restart simulates code package process failures in the cluster, which tests the failover recovery paths of your service.
>
> You can specify a code package, or you can specify a ReplicaSelector to restart the node and code package combination where the replica is hosted. This simplifies tests on the primary host node by not having to determine which Service Fabric node is the primary node before restarting that node.

Comment: Thanks, that didn't solve my problem but it did answer my question :)  The issue was unrelated to SF.